# JS how to stop previous while true when calling it again

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am trying to code a snake game using JS so I am rendering the game using SVG and moving the drawn parts using JS and loops

my problem is that I want to keep the rendering life "The while loop" but Every time I press a new key to change the snake direction The loop call stacks.

I tried looking for ways to stop that but I have no idea.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this problem?

```js
const changeDirection = async key => {
  while(true){
    move(key);
    await sleep(10 * speed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier, rather than keeping track of the interval IDs, to have a single interval which runs persistently. When `changeDirection` is called, just reassign a variable that's referenced inside the interval:

```
let key;
setInterval(() => {
  if (key) {
    move(key);
  }
}, 10 * speed);
const changeDirection = (keyParam) => {
  key = keyParam;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this by using setInterval

```js
let prevKey = // last key stroke
let prevID  = //Interval Id 

const changeDirection = async key => {
  if(prevKey !== key){
    clearInterval(prevID)
    prevKey = key
  }
  prevID = setInterval( () => {
    move(key);
  }, 10 * speed)

}
```

by saving the previous key and the Interval ID and clearing the interval when new valid key event happens